# link queries with realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I have the following classes:

```
import io.realm.RealmList;
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

public class A extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private RealmList<AB> relations = new RealmList<>();
    ...
}

public class B extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private RealmList<AB> relations = new RealmList<>();
    ...
}
```

and

```
import io.realm.RealmObject;
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;

public class AB extends RealmObject{
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String aID;
    private String bID;
    ....
}
```

Let's say I have `a1` and `a2` objects which are in relation with some `b1` and `a2` is in relation with some `b2`.

If I execute the following queries

```
RealmResults<B> test1 = realm.where(B.class)
                             .notEqualTo("relations.aID", a1ID)
                             .findAllSortedAsync("name");
```

I would get as result `b1` and `b2`. Why I get `b2` is pretty clear. I do get `b1` because `a2` is also in relation with `b1` and `a2ID != a1ID`.

My question is to know whether there is a workaround in realm to retrieve only `b2`.

Comment: Why do you have an `AB` class in the first place? Your `A` and `B` could reference each other directly. `RealmList<B>` and `RealmList<A>`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I did have that set up in the first place but it is not enough for my use case. I need an extra class to store some data related to A and B.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is if you bind the referred object into your `Relation` object `AB`

```
public class AB extends RealmObject{
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    private String aID;
    private String bID;

    private A a;
    private B b;
    ....
}
```

Then you execute the query for `AB`

```
RealmResults<AB> results = realm.where(AB.class)
                                .notEqualTo("aID", aID1)
                                .findAllAsyncSorted("name");
```

Because then in your `results`, you'll only have the object where `aID` is not equal to aID1; and then you can refer to `B` with `results.get(i).getB()`.

Answer (score 0):

Extending query this way solve the problem.

```
RealmResults<B> test1 = realm.where(B.class)
                         .findAllSortedAsync("name");
for (AB relation : a1.getRelations()) {
        test1 = test1.where().notEqualTo("id", relation.getBID())
                .findAllSortedAsync("name");
    }
```

Chaining queries actually only works with not Async methods. The above code would the look as follows:

```
RealmResults<B> test1 = realm.where(B.class)
                         .findAllSorted("name");
for (AB relation : a1.getRelations()) {
        test1 = test1.where().notEqualTo("id", relation.getBID())
                .findAllSorted("name");
    }
```

whcih isn't what I want. I definitely need to execute asynchronously